# Finding the distribution of [F; X]

Tags: distributions, covariance, dispersion

I need to find the distribution of \begin{bmatrix}F\\X\end{bmatrix} where  = (F1, F2, X1, X2, X3)^T

[image: Problem]

This is the solution to the problem:
[image: Solution]

I don't really understand the part of $D([F; X])$. Why there are 3 matrix mutiplications and at the end the first matrix is transposed?

Is it because $D(AX) = AD(X)A^T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix):

For any constant (i.e. non-random) $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf {A}$ and constant $m\times 1$ vector $\mathbf {a}$, one has
$$\operatorname {var} (\mathbf {AX} +\mathbf {a} )=\mathbf {A} \,\operatorname {var} (\mathbf {X} )\,\mathbf {A} ^{\rm {T}}$$